# Activity Transition Animations in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-lifecycle

I want to apply an activities transition like the one that HTC phones have: When you start a new Activity there is a slide right-to-left, but when you press the back button to return to the previous Activity, there is a slide left-to-right animation.

I have used `overridePendingTransition` in the `onResume` of my Activities to simulate the slide right to left animation, but when I press the back button, the same animation is executed which is wrong (from a result perspective).

Thus I would like to ask how to manage having different animations for an Activity, one for when it is created, and one for when the user press back key.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To define an animation when the user presses the back button, you have to override `onBackPressed()` in your `Activity` and use `overridePendingTransition()` in there:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
}
```

So this animation will only be shown when the back button gets pressed.

To set an animation when a new Activity opens, you just have to define the animation after you called `startActivity()` or similar:

```
startActivity(some_intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left);
```

Comment: Thanks, I 'll check it out and tell you :)

Comment: what is `anim` in `overridePendingTransition` method. Is it view which we want to animate?

Comment: @I-droid No, it's the animation resource http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View

Comment: But when i use this code, i am getting "Multiple markers at same line" error. Can u explain me why ? and how to get way from that?

Answer (score 0):

you have use default animation in android activity overridePendingTransition

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
```