# animation in setcontetview change

Tags: android, animation, view, translation

i saw some post about this but i didnt succeed .

im using

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

for entire application and i want one activity to just change the view with the same affect .

i saw this solution :

```
boolean isFirstXml=evaluatingConditionFunction();
LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.myfirstxml:R.layout.myseconxml, null, false);
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
setContentView(view);
```

but i didnt realy understand it and it didnt work as i wanted.

example would be great .

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);`
in the beginning i.e. in `onCreate` of another Activity.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260761/activity-transition-animations-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top) may help you

Comment: overridePendingTransition now working on "setcontentview" this is my porblem .