# Animation Transitions during Move from One Activity to Another Activity in Android

Tags: android

I need a Animation transitions when change from one activity another activity in android. The transition like a sliding tabs.

Comment: Search too google .Too old question .

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260761/activity-transition-animations-in-android?rq=1

Comment: I need a transition from left to right..

Comment: I have enough knowledge in animation.

Comment: @Madhur there is no anim file

Comment: you need to create it

Comment: Refer this Answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:create animation files in resources anim directory.**

**pull_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     />
```

**pull_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     />
```

**push_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

**push_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

**Step 2: Implement animation on activity.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
```

Comment: thnks i get the answer but also you answer helped me for future work.thnks

Answer (score 1):

This may be help you

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_from_left, R.anim.hold);
```

Animation file for `pull_in_from_left`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromXDelta="-100%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

You can Modify the `fromXDelta`and `toXDelta` value for Direction Changes.

Comment: Where i put the overridePendingTransition

Comment: before setcontentview

Comment: Thanks for help.Its Worked